# adding new field to table in access using vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013

I get an error in the line with the alter table command. I'm trying to create a field for each month based on the variable monthly using a loop, however it is not going through since I don't get the desired result. The code creates a column called monthly and then gives an error on the second iteration. Code is as follows:

```vb
Dim x As Integer
Dim Months As Integer
Dim monthly As String

Months = Me.YearsBack * 12

Set db = CurrentDb
If Me.Period = "monthly" Then
    For x = 1 To 2
    'Months
    monthly = "WP M" & x
    db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [monthly] string;"
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`[monthly]` is simply part of the string you are executing, it is not automatically resolved from the variable with the same name.

You need string concatenation:

```vb
Dim S As String

S = "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & monthly & "] string;"
Debug.Print S
db.Execute S
```

`Debug.Print` helps with debugging, the output goes to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).

Notice the syntax coloring in the above code.

```
"ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN ["
```

is a constant string.

`&` concatenates strings and variables into a new string.

The [square brackets] are needed because your field names contain spaces (e.g. `WP M2`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I don't understand why we use the symbols [ " & before the variable. Can you explain what each of those does?

Comment: @zkhan: see edit, but I fear that if you are *that* new with coding in VBA, you should look for a tutorial / introduction to VBA, before creating and running ALTER TABLE statements on the fly.